# Child span in Go GRPC opentracing

Tags: go, grpc, jaeger, opentracing, distributed-tracing

I am working on adding opentracing in our micro services, using Jaeger. I have two GRPC server and one REST server.

[image]

The default opentracing with perfectly fine with both GRPC server and all the rest-grpc request are tracked under one parent span. With Java GRPC I am able to add custom child spans and it appears in perfect hierarchy in the Jaeger UI. But When I am trying to add same custom child in Go Lang, it is not added to the parent Rest Service span which has called the GRPC service. Below is the golang code

```
"github.com/opentracing/opentracing-go"

cfg := jaegerConfig.Configuration{
    ServiceName: t.Name,
}

tracer, closer, err := cfg.NewTracer(
    jaegerConfig.Logger(jLogger),
    jaegerConfig.Metrics(jMetricsFactory),
)

gRPCServer := grpc.NewServer(
        grpc.UnaryInterceptor(
            otgrpc.OpenTracingServerInterceptor(tracer)),
        grpc.StreamInterceptor(
            otgrpc.OpenTracingStreamServerInterceptor(tracer)))

var span = tracer.StartSpan("Test Span")
span.SetTag("one", "value")
span.Finish()
```

I do not want to do the whole http headers extraction, as that is already taken care by GRPC library. Even with java GRPC I do not do any extraction. The scope manager that I use with opentracing is not available with go lang opentracing.

Thanks in advance!!!

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with `StartSpanFromContext`, inside your gRPC handlers:

```
    // import "github.com/opentracing/opentracing-go"
    
    span, _ := opentracing.StartSpanFromContext(ctx, "some_child_span")
    defer span.Finish()

    span.SetTag("foo", "bar")
```

As the documentation of `otgrpc.OpenTracingServerInterceptor` says:

> [...] the server Span will be embedded in the context.Context for the
> application-specific gRPC handler(s) to access.

If we look at the function implementation:

```
// import "github.com/opentracing/opentracing-go"

func OpenTracingServerInterceptor(tracer opentracing.Tracer, optFuncs ...Option) grpc.UnaryServerInterceptor {
        // ... a lot omitted
        ctx = opentracing.ContextWithSpan(ctx, serverSpan)
        // ...
        resp, err = handler(ctx, req) // your gRPC handler
        // ...   
}
```

**Edit**: Given the above, you probably can omit this code:

```
var span = tracer.StartSpan("Test Span")
span.SetTag("one", "value")
span.Finish()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am bit of a newbie for GO lang. After your answer I tried that again properly and yes its working. Thanks again.