# start a child span from an existing parent span in Go

Tags: go, grpc, opentracing, distributed-tracing

[I tried using this answer to create a child span from an existing span but it didn't work for me sadly.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62563034/10672994)

I have a parent span starting whenever I make my gRPC call, the code snippet goes like this.

```
type spanctxkey struct{} // pushing span in context to fetch it from anywhere

func StartSpan(ctx context.Context, operationName string) (context.Context, Span) {
parentSpan := sentry.StartSpan(ctx, operationName, sentry.TransactionName(operationName))
return context.WithValue(originalSpan.Context(), spanctxkey{}, &span), Span{
        originalSpan,
    }
}
```

Now, I am trying to get the current running span, from another package, so that I can start a child Span, the code for that is.

```
func getCurrentSpan(ctx context.Context) *Span {
    if span, ok := ctx.Value(spanctxkey{}).(*Span); ok {
        return span
    }
    return nil
}
childSpan := getCurrentSpan(ctx)
fmt.Println(childSpan)
```

When I try to print it, it prints `nil`, I am confused on to why the span is getting closed.

Now the question can be that the parent span might be getting closed before the child span , but no, I added some print statements to verify that as well.

```
--starting span before making a grpc call---
-- starting span before querying the db ---
--closing span after querying the db---
--closing span after making a grpc call---
```

Comment: `from another package,` - `spanctxkey{}` in pkg1 isn't same as `spanctxkey{}` in pkg2`

Comment: Make it exported, then import in pkg2 and try to retrieve again.

Comment: "Now, I am trying to get the current running span, **from another package** — unexported structs in different packages are not the same type so you can't use them to look up values in the context

Comment: let me try that guys, I will update you on that,thanks ❤️

Comment: @OlegButuzov thanks, I was able to grab the running span after making the the type globally like you mentioned above, but how can I start a child span out of it?.
`runningSpan := ctx.Value(apm.Spanctxkey{}).(**apm.Span)` and my runningSpan is of type `var runningSpan **apm.Span`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to `span.StartChild("foobar")` ? (I am judging based on [sentry](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-go/blob/8fbb027528f9464e0233afa756cef0f99bd70906/tracing.go#L190) sdk)